# How can I compare the one line in one CSV with all lines in another CSV file?

Tags: sql-server, csv, apache-nifi

I have two CSV files:

1. `Identity(no,name,Age)` which has 10 rows
2. `Location(Address,no,City)` which has 100 rows

I need to extract rows and check the `no` column in the `Identity` with `Location` CSV files.

Get the single row from `Identity` CSV file and check `Identity.no` with `Location.no` having 100 rows in `Location` CSV file.

If it is matching then combine the `name, Age, Address, City` in `Identity, Location`

Note: I need to get 1st row from `Identity` compare it with 100 rows in `Location` CSV file and then get the 2nd row compare it with 100 rows. It will be continue up to 10 rows in `Identity` CSV file.

And overall results convert into Json.Then move the results in to SQL Server.

**Is it possible in Apache Nifi?**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Import the csv files into two tables in sql server then create a cursor

Comment: @Fourat Thanks for your reply. I have to perform those operations only in Apache Nifi Because I need to add expression languge support into csv data using nifi processors. So Not to be done it in SQL Server

Comment: Sorry can't help you with Nifi :/

Comment: @Fourat Thanks for your response

Comment: What is the relation between the `sql-server` tag and your question? If your question is not about SQL Server, I suggest you remove the tag.

Comment: @TT I need to move that data into SQL Server So i have added SQL Server tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in NiFi by using the DistributedMapCache feature, which implements a key/value store for lookups.  The setup requires a distributed map cache, plus two flows - one to populate the cache with your Address records, and one to look up the address by the `no` field.

1. The DistributedMapCache is defined by two controller services, a [DistributedMapCacheServer](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer/index.html) and a [DistributeMapCacheClientService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.DistributedMapCacheClientService/index.html).  If your data set is small, you can just use "localhost" as the server.
2. Populating the cache requires reading the Address file, splitting the records, extracting the `no` key, and putting key/value pairs to the cache.  An approximate flow might include GetFile -> SplitText -> ExtractText -> UpdateAttribute -> [PutDistributedMapCache](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDistributedMapCache/index.html).
3. Looking up your identity records is actually fairly similar to the flow above, in that it requires reading the Identity file, splitting the records, extracting the `no` key, and then fetching the address record.  Processor flow might include GetFile -> SplitText -> ExtractText -> UpdateAttribute -> [FetchDistributedMapCache](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchDistributedMapCache/index.html).

You can convert the whole or parts from CSV to JSON with AttributesToJSON, or maybe ExecuteScript.

Comment: The above flow will extract the matched values in the address file only, but i need some values in identity files also, like if "no" matched on both files it should return "Address,no,city,Name,Age" . Does it possible to do so ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but NiFi does not do relational joins like a database.  What I've outlined above is a way to look up the matching Address record from a flowfile containing an Identity record.  Defining the joined result requires an AttributesToJSON, ExecuteScript, or perhaps just ReplaceText to format your `Address,no,city,Name,Age` target.

Comment: Thanks, I can able to get the values. now i want to compare this result in to another CSV.. Please suggest any idea.