# How to compare two CSV file in Nifi?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

Is it possible to compare two csv files in nifi(1.7) using groovy script? One file is at SFTP server and other is flow file. Problem is similar to that of link given below.

I have tried the approach given in link below :-
[How can I compare the one line in one CSV with all lines in another CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673060/how-can-i-compare-the-one-line-in-one-csv-with-all-lines-in-another-csv-file)

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you face?  Is the problem related to the locations or the plain comparing part?  If you have tried said approach, what did not work, what errors did you get etc?

Comment: @cfrick  Approach posted in the link has worked now. Errors are coming because I have not configured  DistributedMapCacheServer correctly. Thanks :)